# PHP, Razorpay - 'Authentication error' message shows up even after passing right keys

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, razorpay

//get_items.php//

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alkatra' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <title>Checkout</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $item = $_GET['item'];
        $price = $_GET['price'];
    ?>
    <header>
        <h1>Items</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
        <h2><?php echo $item; ?></h2>  
        <p>Price: <strong id="item-price"><?php echo $price; ?></strong></p>
        
        <!-- Plus and minus buttons for quantity -->
        <button type="button" class="quantity-btn" onclick="updateQuantity('minus', '<?php echo $item; ?>', '<?php echo $price; ?>')">-</button>
        <!-- Make the quantity field read-only -->
        <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" readonly>
        <button type="button" class="quantity-btn" onclick="updateQuantity('plus', '<?php echo $item; ?>', '<?php echo $price; ?>')">+</button>

        <!-- Display total price -->
        <p>Total Price: Rs:<strong id="total-price"><?php echo number_format($price, 2); ?></strong></p>

        <!-- Add hidden input fields for item and price -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $item; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">

        <!-- Styled hyperlink with data attributes -->
        <button type="submit">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right buy_now"
           data-amount="<?php echo $price * 100; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $item; ?>">
                Order Now
            </a>
        </button>
        <!-- Original "Cancel and Return back" button -->
        <button><a href="index.html">Cancel and Return back</a></button>
    </form>

    <!-- Razorpay scripts -->
    <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Script for Razorpay integration
        $('body').on('click', '.buy_now', function(e){
            var totalAmount = $(this).attr("data-amount");
            var product_id =  $(this).attr("data-id");
            var options = {
                "key": "rzp_test_ABd1v6TpL4C5Nj",
                "amount": totalAmount,
                "description": "Payment",
                "handler": function (response){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://stripe_payment_gateway.dvl.to/checkout.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            razorpay_payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id,
                            totalAmount: totalAmount,
                            product_id: product_id,
                        },
                        success: function (msg) {
                            window.location.href = 'http://stripe_payment_gateway.dvl.to/success.php';
                        }
                    });
                },
                "theme": {
                    "color": "#528FF0"
                }
            };
            var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
            rzp1.open();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Function to update quantity and total price -->
    <script>
        function updateQuantity(action, item, price) {
            var quantityInput = document.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]');
            var quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);

            if (action === 'plus') {
                quantity += 1;
            } else if (action === 'minus' && quantity > 1) {
                quantity -= 1;
            }

            quantityInput.value = quantity;

            var itemPrice = parseFloat(price);
            var totalPrice = quantity * itemPrice;

            document.getElementById('total-price').textContent = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

//checkout.php//

```
<?php

require __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";


// Replace 'your_key_id' and 'your_secret_key' with your actual Razorpay key and secret
$razorpay_key_id = 'rzp_test_ABd1v6TpL4C5Nj';
$razorpay_secret_key = 'Aa7mPGeW85KQSddn1NDl3vq7';

use \Razorpay\Api\Api;

// Create an instance of the Razorpay client
$razorpay = new Api($razorpay_key_id, $razorpay_secret_key);


// Debugging: Output the content of the $_POST array
var_dump($_POST);

// Check if the required keys are present in the $_POST array
if (isset($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']) && isset($_POST['totalAmount']) && isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
    $razorpay_payment_id = $_POST['razorpay_payment_id'];
    $totalAmount = $_POST['totalAmount'];
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    // Verify the payment using Razorpay SDK
    try {
        $attributes = array(
            'razorpay_payment_id' => $razorpay_payment_id,
            'razorpay_signature' => $_POST['razorpay_signature'],
        );

        $razorpay->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attributes);
        
        // Your further processing logic here

        $response = array("msg" => "Payment successfully credited", "status" => true);
        echo json_encode($response);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle the case when payment verification fails
        $response = array("msg" => "Payment verification failed", "status" => false);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // Handle the case when keys are not present
    $response = array("msg" => "Missing required parameters", "status" => false);
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

After clicking on "order item" button, I am seeing this popup:

> Oops!Something went wrong

> Authentication error

As far as I undertood, I am doing something wrong in buy_items.php and I have my rzp.csv file. I have modified and updated the code several times, still the error persists.